# pycharm not inspecting imports correctly

Tags: pycharm

For the directory structure below, pycharm can't seem to detect an import from one file to another

- `puzzle_project`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `snippets`

    - `__init__.py`
    - `models.py`
    - `views.py`

For models.py the code is:

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())


class Snippet (models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

for views.py the code is:

```
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
```

views.py will run but pycharm marks these lines as an Unresolved Refrence. Only when I rewrite the lines like this:

```
from puzzle_project.snippets.models import Snippet
from puzzle_project.snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
```

will pycharm not declare an unresolved reference. Note that the code above will not run in python.

Please note I am using the latest version of pycharm and python 3.4

How will I get pycharm to correctly inspect these lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the project structure in the preferences. Make sure the root is set correctly. The inspector inspects code with this setting as the current working directory.

The inspector marked certain things as wrong because if I ran the interpreter from the same directory as the root setting I would get the same error. Thus to fix the error, either change the root setting in the project structure preferences for pycharm OR change the cwd of where you run the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the directory that should be the root of your project and choose "Mark Directory as" then "Sorces Root". This should solve.

See this image:

[image: Defining the root directory]